# Binary operators - Operand types supposed to be identical?

Tags: go

In the below code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

    a := 1e6
    b := 2
    fmt.Println(b / a) 
    fmt.Println(2 / a) 
}
```

---

why `2/a` is valid syntax?

Why `b/a` is an invalid syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why `2/a` is valid syntax?

"For other binary operators, the operand types must be identical unless the operation involves shifts or untyped constants.". `2` is an untyped constant.

> Why `b/a` is an invalid syntax?

It isn't. It's syntactically perfectly valid; it's just *semantically* wrong because it's an operation on mismatched types.

Answer (score 2):

It is not invalid syntax. It is mismatched types:

```
invalid operation: b / a (mismatched types int and float64)
```

For binary operations, types must be identical.
`b` is an `int`, and `a` is a `float64`, so to perform an operation, you have to be explicit about the types:

```
float64(b)/a
```

This would make both operands `float64`. So would:

```
b/int(a)
```

where both operands are `int`.

This is not a problem for `2/a` because `2` is an untyped constant, and its actual type is determined based on context. Since `a` is `float64`, in this case `2` is a `float64`.

Comment: For other binary operators, the operand types must be identical unless the operation involves shifts or untyped constants....https://golang.org/ref/spec#Operators

Answer (score 2):

Other answers offer good points, I just wanted to add how I remember the rules. First this example:

```
a := 1e6
b := 2
fmt.Println(b / a)
```

With this example, both values are "type locked", that is to say, you're performing the division after declaring a type for each variable. Since the types don't match, the operation fails:

```
invalid operation: b / a (mismatched types int and float64)
```

This example:

```
a := 1e6
fmt.Println(2 / a)
```

Now `2` has not be assigned a type, so it can essentially be any numerical type. Since `a` is `float64`, then `2` just says "OK I will be `float64` too", and the division is successful.